# Laravel : Sending a Email to a email address which is inside the database by user ID

Tags: database, laravel, email, button

```
[enter image description here][1]
```

//blade.php file

```
      @foreach ($data as $row)

        <th scope="row">{{$row->id}}</th>
        <td>{{$row->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$row->email}}</td>
        <td></td>
      <td><a href="/send-email/{{$row->id}}"><button type="button"class="btn btn-success">CheckIn</button></a></td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info">View</button></td>

      </tr>
      @endforeach
```

//JoinTableController Controller

```
    public function sendEmail(id $id)
        {

            Mail::to($data->email)->send(new ThankyouMail());
            return back();
        }
```

my route

```
   Route::get('/send-email/{id}','JoinTableController@sendEmail');
```

I want to send an email to the email address of the user which is inside the database by clicking a button here are my blade file controller and the route can someone help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the user by provided id and send the mail if the user exists like:

```
public function sendEmail($id)
        {
            $user = User::find($id);

            if(!empty($user){
                   Mail::to($user->email)->send(new ThankyouMail());
            }                

            return back();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is 
In your controller logic

```
public function sendEmail($id)
{
  $email = User::find($id)->email;
  Mail::to($email)->send(new ThankyouMail());
  return back();
}
```